# Testing Rails controller security with RSpec shared examples

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller

Some months ago, I came across an article on the web describing RSpec controller tests, using shared **examples**, and making distinction between **various user/access roles**…  …I should have saved the link, cause no matter how hard I’ve been googeling, I can’t find it back.

Can any of you refer me to such a framework? Or has any of you created one of your own? 
I’ve been reading Aaron Sumner’s book on controller tests, as well as Mike Subelsky’s blog. I’ve also looked into https://github.com/svs/painless_controller_tests.

The article I'm referring to really used a **declarative approach** to define the various actions each role could access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the article: https://github.com/edspencer/rspec-crud-controller-shared-example-groups

As this isn't using the "new" rspec syntax (it dates back to 2008), and isn't even working anymore with the current RSpec version, I had to make my own "variation", but the concept is definitely Ed Spencer's!

A "standard" CRUD controller test can now be written as:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe XxxController do
  it_behaves_like 'an unauthorized controller', as: [:user, :guest]
  it_behaves_like 'an authorized controller', as: :admin    
end
```

I love DRY!

Comment: This answer could be improved by including code snippets for the shared examples. Would you mind adding them?